# First Table in document coming up as Table 2 - can't find any reason for this (no previous \table or \tabular) LaTeX

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

I've added in the first table to my document, and it is coming up as table 2...  This is also the case for the list of tables where it comes up as table 2 with no table 1. I have not used `\begin{table}`, nor `\begin{tabular}` anywhere else in the document.

Any ideas would be welcome!! :)

Code is below, removing `\printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long] \gls{DOHaD}`  for some reason returns the table as table 1.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,A4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=4.32cm,top=2.54cm,right=2.29cm,bottom=2.03cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}                    
\graphicspath{./images/}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage[style=long,nonumberlist,toc,xindy,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}   
\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries[acronym]{Abbreviations}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long]
\gls{DOHaD}  

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
TABLE
\end{tabular}
\caption{Descriptive stats etc etc.}
\label{Table 1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Abbreviations.tex is a seperated file with the following in:

```
 \newacronym{DOHaD}{DOHaD}{Developmental Origins of Health and Disease}
```

Comment: please make a small complete document that shows the problem, it is impossible to say anything to help given the information you have posted so far

Comment: I am, as you can probably tell, really new to all this.  Would a skeleton version of my script do the job? (I.e. I'll just remove all text essentially?)

Comment: start from a copy of your document, remove everything after the table, remove everything before the table, replace every word by zzz if you wish, remove any package not used in the remaining example, and check at each stage that the problem is still there. If you remove something and the  problem goes, you have found the solution yourself.

Comment: That was great advise I definitely should have thought of myself..

\printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long]

\gls{DOHaD}

Removing these two lines got rid of the issue but I am clueless as to why they are interfering..

Comment: still if you can make a small example that we can run someone can trace and see what the issue is.

Comment: Edited wiht an example of the troublesome parts!

Comment: The glossaries doesn't seem to have run in that output, which is what is causing the table 2 issues in mine. When i remove the \printglossary section my output looks like yours.

I think i just edited your response away... woops, sorry.

Comment: Ah OK confirmed, sorry for first reply, you need pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex and it comes out as 2, weird... I'll look...

Comment: Oh OK I see, I'll post an answer

Comment: all that and it turns out it's my code that incremented the table counter, I honestly hadn't even guessed that at the start:-)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much for the help and patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style=long` attribute causes the `longtable` package to be used to set the glossary table. There is then a hidden feature that causes the `table` counter to be incremented.  It's debatable whether to blame `longtable` for incrementing the counter or `glossaries` for not knowing that the longtable increments the counter and adjusting it. Personally I'd blame `glossaries` (as otherwise I'd have to blame myself, which is clearly a bad plan)

The fix is simply to set the counter back:

```
\printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long]
\setcounter{table}{0}
```

the fact that `longtable` increments the counter isn't its best feature (there is some code in an experimental version 5 that stops that, but longtable v5 isn't ready for release) so setting the counter here is a safe workaround, but arguably glossaries should do this as it knows it is calling `longtable` without a `\caption` which is what causes the missing table entry.